# Warshall algorithm idea and improvement

Tags: c, algorithm, graph

[The Warshall-Floyd algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd%E2%80%93Warshall_algorithm) is based on essentially the idea: exploit a relationship between a problem and its simpler rather than smaller version. Warshall and Floyd published their algorithms without mentioning dynamic programming. Nevertheless, the algorithms certainly have a dynamic programming flavor and have come to be considered applications of this technique.

```
ALGORITHM Warshall(A[1..n, 1..n])
    //ImplementsWarshall’s algorithm for computing the transitive closure
    //Input: The adjacency matrix A of a digraph with n vertices
    //Output: The transitive closure of the digraph
    R(0) ←A
    for k←1 to n do
        for i ←1 to n do
            for j ←1 to n do
                R(k)[i, j ]←R(k−1)[i, j ] or (R(k−1)[i, k] and R(k−1)[k, j])
    return R(n)
```

We can speed up the above implementation of Warshall’s algorithm for some inputs by restructuring its innermost loop

My question on above text are following

1. What does author mean by idea is " exploit a relationship between a problem and its simpler rather than smaller version" Please elobaorate.
2. How can we improve speed as author mentioned in above implemenation.

Comment: 1. Arguably there's really no 100% clear line separating "simpler" and "smaller" subproblems, but in the case of FW, the subproblem solved has an additional constraint (the internal vertices of paths are forbidden to use vertices with numbers > k) instead of being the same as the original problem, but on a subset of the vertices (as is often the case with other DP algorithms).

Comment: 2. TTBOMK all known solutions to the All Pairs Shortest Paths problem better than FW's O(n^3) use fast matrix multiplication techniques, which only decrease the exponent 3 a little bit and tend not to actually be practical at realistic problem sizes -- so I don't know what the author is talking about there.

Answer (score 0):

The formulation from 1. means that the shortest path problem (which can be seen as a generalization of the transitive closure problem) has the [optimal substructure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimal_substructure) property; however for this property does not exist a formal description (in the sense of a mathematical definition). The optimal substructure property is necessary for a problem to be amenable to dynamic programming.