# Warshall algorithm idea and possible improvement

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm

Warshall's algorithm for computing the transitive closure of a digraph typically takes the following form (from [Warshall algorithm idea and improvement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31293498/warshall-algorithm-idea-and-improvement)):

```
ALGORITHM Warshall(A[1..n, 1..n])
    //ImplementsWarshall’s algorithm for computing the transitive closure
    //Input: The adjacency matrix A of a digraph with n vertices
    //Output: The transitive closure of the digraph
    R(0) ←A
    for k←1 to n do
        for i ←1 to n do
            for j ←1 to n do
                R(k)[i, j ]←R(k−1)[i, j ] or (R(k−1)[i, k] and R(k−1)[k, j])
    return R(n)
```

But we could speed up the above implementation by noticing that there is no update if |i-j| <= k, so we can skip running the update in that case.

Am I missing something? Does this kind of improvement not impact the runtime? (I haven't taken the time yet to calculate the runtime for that version.)

Comment: what's the point of taking the difference of i and j ? kth matrix contains closures involving nodes 1 .. k on the way from i to j. how k is related to the difference between i and j ?

Comment: @mangusta - The idea of k is that, if there is a path from i to k, and from k to j, then there exists a path from i to j. If the i and i are not k-node apart, then such exercise is not revealing anything meaningful.

Comment: i and j is just a node ID. the difference of node IDs has nothing to do with the number of nodes apart

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're missing is that `|i - j|` is not related to the distance between `i` and `j`.

What Warshal's Algorithm does at iteration k is to determine if there exists a path between *the vertex labeled* i and *the vertex labeled* j using only vertices among `{1, ..., k}` as intermediates. Hence, `R(k)[i,j]` should equal to 1 if any one of the following two conditions holds:

1. `R(k-1)[i,j] = 1`. That is, there exists a path between vertex i and vertex j using only vertices among `{1, ..., k-1}` as intermediates.
2. `R(k−1)[i, k] and R(k−1)[k, j]`. That is, there exists a path from vertex i to vertex k and there exists a path from vertex k to vertex j, each using only vertices among `{1, ..., k-1}` as intermediates.

The values of `i` or `j` (and `|i-j|` for that matter) have nothing to do with the distances between vertex `i` and vertex `j`. They're arbitrary labels serving as identifiers for the vertices.

Comment: @ snakile - Got the mistake in my understanding. Thanks. Btw, still got a hunch that there might be some more optimization we can do. When I do some iterations by hand, feels like many cycles are going by without any updates.

Comment: @KGhatak nothing can be optimized in this algorithm. Every single check out of those i * j * k checks is necessary to determine all closures between every possible pair [ i , j ]